# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element Media

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've generated below XML

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<catalogue xmlns="http://api.anteenaa.com/schemas/brand/v3/product">
    <products>
        <product>
            <brandProductId>414367</brandProductId>
            <categoryCodes>
                <categoryCode>DAY DRESSES (0002)</categoryCode>
            </categoryCodes>
            <productNames>
                <productName>Nola Animal Dress</productName>
            </productNames>
            <productShortDescriptions>
                <productShortDescription>Nola Animal Dress</productShortDescription>
            </productShortDescriptions>
            <productLongDescriptions>
                <productLongDescription>A standout print of exotic animals makes our Nola dress for girls a bright idea for daytime dos. With a scallop hem, sequin embellishments and tassel neckline, this colourful cotton number will have all eyes on her style. It features a bow and cut-out detail at the back, and is fully lined.</productLongDescription>
            </productLongDescriptions>
            <season>SS18</season>
            <genders>
                <gender>Girls</gender>
            </genders>
            <sizeGridCode>8</sizeGridCode>
            <materialComposition>
                <compositionComponent componentName="Outer">
                    <material name="Polyester" percentage="100"/>
                    <material name="Cotton Trim" percentage="100"/>
                    <material name="Cotton Lining" percentage="100"/>
                </compositionComponent>
            </materialComposition>
            <productCommonAttributes>
                <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_comp_lining">cotton</productCommonAttribute>
                <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_comp_outer">cotton</productCommonAttribute>
                <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_style">Dress</productCommonAttribute>
                <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_type">Dress</productCommonAttribute>
            </productCommonAttributes>
            <productCategoryAttributes>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="det_occasion">Leisure</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="form_neckline">Round</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="form_trouser_rise">Short</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="info_countryOrigin">IND</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="info_exclusivity">None</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="info_guarantee">n/a</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="IronMethod">Refer to product label</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="ironTemp">Cool Iron</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="washMethod">machine wash</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="washTemp">40</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="waterproof">false</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="beltIncluded">false</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="dressDetail">Other</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="fasteningType">No fastensing</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="waterResistant">n/a</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="dim_length_overall_desc">Short</productCategoryAttribute>
                <productCategoryAttribute key="dim_length_sleeve_desc">Sleeveless</productCategoryAttribute>
            </productCategoryAttributes>
            <articles>
                <article>
                    <brandArticleSku>4143672632</brandArticleSku>
                    <ean>5045461435478</ean>
                    <brandProductLineId>41436726</brandProductLineId>
                    <sizeGridValue>12-13 Years</sizeGridValue>
                    <brandColourNames>
                        <brandColourName locale="gb_EN">Ivory</brandColourName>
                    </brandColourNames>
                    <colourCodes>
                        <colourCode rank="3">26</colourCode>
                    </colourCodes>
                    <articleMedia>
                        <media>
                            <mediaType>Images</mediaType>
                            <sortOrder>3</sortOrder>
                        </media>
                    </articleMedia>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <brandArticleSku>4143672633</brandArticleSku>
                    <ean>5045461435409</ean>
                    <brandProductLineId>41436726</brandProductLineId>
                    <sizeGridValue>5 Years</sizeGridValue>
                    <brandColourNames>
                        <brandColourName locale="gb_EN">Ivory</brandColourName>
                    </brandColourNames>
                    <colourCodes>
                        <colourCode rank="3">26</colourCode>
                    </colourCodes>
                    <articleMedia>
                        <media>
                            <mediaType>Images</mediaType>
                            <sortOrder>3</sortOrder>
                        </media>
                    </articleMedia>
                </article>
            </articles>
        </product>
    </products>
</catalogue>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/product"
           targetNamespace="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/product"
           xmlns:common="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes" schemaLocation="commonTypes.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="catalogue">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="header"/>
                <xs:element name="products">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="product" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="header">
        <xs:complexType >
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="brandLogo"  type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="brandProductId" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="categoryCodes" type="categoryCodes"/>
                <xs:element name="productNames" type="productNames"/>
                <xs:element name="productShortDescriptions" type="productShortDescriptions"/>
                <xs:element name="productLongDescriptions" type="productLongDescriptions"/>
                <xs:element name="season" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="genders" type="genders"/>
                <xs:element name="sizeGridCode" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="materialComposition" type="materialComposition"/>
                <xs:element name="productSubBrandCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="productCommonAttributes" type="productCommonAttributes" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="productCategoryAttributes" type="productCategoryAttributes" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="keywords" type="keywords" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="productBullets" type="productBullets" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="productDeliveryServiceCodes" type="productDeliveryServiceCodes" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="extensions" type="common:extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="articles">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="article" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="categoryCodes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="categoryCode" type="categoryCode" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="genders">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="gender" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productName">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" use="optional" name="locale"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productNames">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productName" type="productName" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productShortDescriptions">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productShortDescription" type="common:localeDescription" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productLongDescriptions">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productLongDescription" type="common:localeDescription" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productCommonAttributes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productCommonAttribute" type="productAttribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productCategoryAttributes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productCategoryAttribute" type="productAttribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productBullets">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="bulletSet" type="bulletSet" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="bulletSet">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="productBullet" type="productBullet" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="locale" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productDeliveryServiceCodes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="deliveryServiceCode" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productAttribute">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="productBullet">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="article">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="brandArticleSku" type="common:brandArticleSku"/>
                <xs:element name="ean" type="common:ean"/>
                <xs:element name="brandProductLineId" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="sizeGridValue" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="perpetualStock" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="brandColourNames" type="brandColourNames"/>
                <xs:element name="colourCodes" type="colourCodes"/>
                <xs:element name="articleMedia" type="common:articleMedia" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="CategoryAttributes" type="categoryAttributes" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="extensions" type="common:extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="channels" type="channels"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- channels type Definition -->
    <xs:complexType name="channels">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="countryChannel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="wholesale" minOccurs="0" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        <xs:element name="excludeRetailerChannels" minOccurs="0">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="excludeRetailerChannel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="price" type="price" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="countryCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="active" type="xs:boolean" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="retailerChannel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="wholesale" minOccurs="0" type="xs:boolean"/>
                        <xs:element name="price" type="price" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="channelCode" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="active" type="xs:boolean" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="price">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="priceContextCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="currency" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="brandRRP" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="currentPrice" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="previousPrice" minOccurs="0" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="vatTreatmentCode" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="extensions" minOccurs="0" type="common:extensions"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="colourCodes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="colourCode" type="colourCode" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="brandColourNames">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="brandColourName" type="common:localeDescription" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="categoryAttributes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="categoryAttribute" type="productAttribute" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="articleMedia">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="media" type="media" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="media">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mediaType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="mediaURL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="mediaFileReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="sortOrder" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="extensions" type="common:extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="categoryCode">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="colourCode">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="rank" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="keywords">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="keywordSet" type="keywordSet" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="keywordSet">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="keyword" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="locale" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="materialComposition">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="compositionComponent" type="compositionComponent" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="compositionComponent">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="material" type="material" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="componentName" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="material">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="percentage" type="common:percentage" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

While validating the xml its showing error like this

```
[{"inputErrorMessage":"cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element mediaType. One of {\"http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes\":media} is expected.
```

I have seen max all post related to this issue on stackoverflow and googled as well, but firstly am not able to understand why its happening and what could be the fix..?

Can anyone help to understand this issue and fix this...? Its my 3rd day spending on this issue..!

Update :

```
    <common:articleMedia>
                            <common:media>
                                <common:mediaType>Images</mediaType>
                                <common:sortOrder>3</sortOrder>
                            </common:media>
  </common:articleMedia>
```

commonTypes.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes"
           xmlns="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="brandCode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!--   ean type Definition (11 to 13 digits) -->
    <xs:simpleType name="ean">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(\\s|[0-9]{11,13})?" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- brandsku type Definition  -->
    <xs:simpleType  name="brandArticleSku">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- percentage type Definition  -->
    <xs:simpleType name="percentage">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="extension">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="extensionName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="extensionValue" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- address type Definition    -->
        <xs:complexType name="address">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="retailerCustomerNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="address1" type="AddressStringType"/>
                <xs:element name="address2" type="AddressStringType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="address3" type="AddressStringType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="address4" type="AddressStringType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="address5" type="AddressStringType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="address6" type="AddressStringType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="zip" type="AddressStringType"/>
                <xs:element name="city" type="AddressStringType"/>
                <xs:element name="state" type="AddressStringType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="country" type="AddressStringType"/>
                <xs:element name="addressString" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="email" type="email"/>
                <xs:element name="homeTel" minOccurs="0" type="telephone"/>
                <xs:element name="mobileTel" minOccurs="0" type="telephone"/>
                <xs:element name="workTel" minOccurs="0" type="telephone"/>
                <xs:element name="extensions" type="extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Standard Address String Type    -->
    <xs:simpleType name="AddressStringType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- email type Definition -->
    <xs:simpleType name="email">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- telephone type Definition -->
    <xs:simpleType name="telephone">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- money type Definition -->
    <xs:simpleType name="money">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!--  Generic Price Type definition -->
    <xs:simpleType name="priceType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <!-- Price must be Greater than Zero -->
            <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
            <!-- Maximum of 2DP supported  -->
            <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!-- type extensions Definition -->
    <xs:complexType name="extensions">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="extension" type="extension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="localeDescription">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="locale" type="localeType"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="localeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="5" />
            <xs:pattern value="[a-z]{2}(_|-)[A-Z]{2}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="articleMedia">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="media" type="media" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="media">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mediaType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="mediaURL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="mediaFileReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="sortOrder" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="extensions" type="extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous corrections needed to your XML file, including:

1. Changed encoding to be UTF-8 rather than UTF-16 (but if your data is 
   truly UTF-16, you needn't change this).
2. Defined `common:` namespace prefix and used it on `media`, `mediaType`,
   and `sortOrder` elements.
3. Added several missing required elements per the XSD.
4. Fixed typos in namespaces: `anteena.com`, not `anteenaa.com`.

Here is your XML file made to be valid against your XSDs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalogue xmlns="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/product"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:common="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/product try.xsd">

  <header/>
  <products>
    <product>
      <brandProductId>414367</brandProductId>
      <categoryCodes>
        <categoryCode>DAY DRESSES (0002)</categoryCode>
      </categoryCodes>
      <productNames>
        <productName>Nola Animal Dress</productName>
      </productNames>
      <productShortDescriptions>
        <productShortDescription>Nola Animal Dress</productShortDescription>
      </productShortDescriptions>
      <productLongDescriptions>
        <productLongDescription>A standout print of exotic animals makes our Nola dress for girls a bright idea for daytime dos. With a scallop hem, sequin embellishments and tassel neckline, this colourful cotton number will have all eyes on her style. It features a bow and cut-out detail at the back, and is fully lined.</productLongDescription>
      </productLongDescriptions>
      <season>SS18</season>
      <genders>
        <gender>Girls</gender>
      </genders>
      <sizeGridCode>8</sizeGridCode>
      <materialComposition>
        <compositionComponent componentName="Outer">
          <material name="Polyester" percentage="100"/>
          <material name="Cotton Trim" percentage="100"/>
          <material name="Cotton Lining" percentage="100"/>
        </compositionComponent>
      </materialComposition>
      <productCommonAttributes>
        <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_comp_lining">cotton</productCommonAttribute>
        <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_comp_outer">cotton</productCommonAttribute>
        <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_style">Dress</productCommonAttribute>
        <productCommonAttribute key="AP01_type">Dress</productCommonAttribute>
      </productCommonAttributes>
      <productCategoryAttributes>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="det_occasion">Leisure</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="form_neckline">Round</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="form_trouser_rise">Short</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="info_countryOrigin">IND</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="info_exclusivity">None</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="info_guarantee">n/a</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="IronMethod">Refer to product label</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="ironTemp">Cool Iron</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="washMethod">machine wash</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="washTemp">40</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="waterproof">false</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="beltIncluded">false</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="dressDetail">Other</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="fasteningType">No fastensing</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="waterResistant">n/a</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="dim_length_overall_desc">Short</productCategoryAttribute>
        <productCategoryAttribute key="dim_length_sleeve_desc">Sleeveless</productCategoryAttribute>
      </productCategoryAttributes>
      <articles>
        <article>
          <brandArticleSku>4143672632</brandArticleSku>
          <ean>5045461435478</ean>
          <brandProductLineId>41436726</brandProductLineId>
          <sizeGridValue>12-13 Years</sizeGridValue>
          <brandColourNames>
            <brandColourName locale="gb_EN">Ivory</brandColourName>
          </brandColourNames>
          <colourCodes>
            <colourCode rank="3">26</colourCode>
          </colourCodes>
          <articleMedia>
            <common:media>
              <common:mediaType>Images</common:mediaType>
              <common:sortOrder>3</common:sortOrder>
            </common:media>
          </articleMedia>
          <channels/>
        </article>
        <article>
          <brandArticleSku>4143672633</brandArticleSku>
          <ean>5045461435409</ean>
          <brandProductLineId>41436726</brandProductLineId>
          <sizeGridValue>5 Years</sizeGridValue>
          <brandColourNames>
            <brandColourName locale="gb_EN">Ivory</brandColourName>
          </brandColourNames>
          <colourCodes>
            <colourCode rank="3">26</colourCode>
          </colourCodes>
          <articleMedia>
            <common:media>
              <common:mediaType>Images</common:mediaType>
              <common:sortOrder>3</common:sortOrder>
            </common:media>
          </articleMedia>
          <channels/>
        </article>
      </articles>
    </product>
  </products>
</catalogue>
```

Comment: tell me one thing, How do you get to know that media tags should have common namespace along with that ? Because there are so many tags who are in commonTypes.xsd but not using common namespace in XML and working..!

Comment: Because the `media` element is declared in commonTypes.xsd, which has a target namespace of  `http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes`.  Don't be misled by the types; `articleMedia` has a type in commonTypes.xsd but the element itself is declared in the base XSD, which has a target namespace of `http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/product`.

Comment: thanks a lot your detailed desc, but am sorry am still little confused to get it. Is that possible you could share with me more explanation so that I could understand it...? I really want to know how tags are being diverted b/w namespaces to two different XSDs

Comment: media is under articleMedia which is declared in base XSD and commonTypes.xsd as well. Then how did you get to know articleMedia is using http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/product namespace and media is using http://api.anteena.com/schemas/brand/v3/commonTypes namesapce ?

Comment: You seem to have (1) missed the meaning of `<xs:element name="articleMedia" type="common:articleMedia" minOccurs="0"/>` and  (2) become confused by another, *different* type declaration of `articleMedia` in the base XSD.

Comment: So you mean all the tags declared in commonTypes.xsd should be having common as namespace along with their tag in XML ..? if I take a example of brandArticleSku, its only type definition is declared in commonTypes.xsd not the element itself that's why we are not using common with it, Correct....?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: @kjhughes...Thanks for your time...!

Comment: @Squeez: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Please do ***not*** delete your question again.  I spent time to help not only you but future readers as well, and deleting your question after receiving help would be a disservice both to future readers and to me.  Thanks.